# INS-40719 error when Install Oracle RAC?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-rac

I'm tying to (learn how to) install Oracle RAC 11g on CentOS 6
all went OK so far but I get INS-40719 Error message regarding SCAN Name

I do not have DNS server and I'm not going to try to use it on this setup

I add this line to /etc/hosts

```
192.168.244.100 rac-cluster
```

then used "rac-cluster" as the SCAN name and it's still not working with the same error message!

any one can guide me on how to make it work?

1- do I have to add "192.168.244.100 rac-cluster" to /etc/hosts on both nodes?

2- do I need to edit/add any thing else on the nodes?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use /etc/hosts for RAC SCAN, it needs a DNS server that have round robin name resolution capability. Its a requirement - refer [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/clustering/overview/scan-129069.pdf) the official Oracle documentation on SCAN.

Refer [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/dns-configuration-for-scan.php) on how to configure dns for RAC SCAN.

Comment: what about this ---> http://dba-star.blogspot.com/2011/10/ins-40922-invalid-scan-name-unresolved.html

Comment: I just installed BIND on the SAN (CentOS) and used it
Thanks allot :-)

Comment: its a hard coded workaround... but even in the article, the author said it should not be used in production.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this also may helps you:

[Oracle 12c RAC installation on Linux using DNS.](http://www.dbacentral.com/2016/12/oracle-12c-rac-installation-on-linux-7.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.